# MySQL Syntax Error Exception while executing JPQL in spring project

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql, spring-jdbc

Above is the JPA Class

```
public class UsersDaoJpa extends BaseDaoJpa<Users> implements UsersDao {

    public UsersDaoJpa() {
        super(Users.class, "Users");
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> findByRegisteredUserEmail(String emailId) {
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT us FROM Users AS us WHERE us.emailId =:emailId");
        query.setParameter("emailId", emailId);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> findByRegisteredUserPhone(String mobileNo) {
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT us FROM Users AS us WHERE us.mobileNo =:mobileNo");
        query.setParameter("mobileNo", mobileNo);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> FindUsersByEmailPhoneRole(String emailId, String mobileNo, String userRole) {
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT us FROM Users AS us WHERE us.mobileNo =:mobileNo AND us.emailId =:emailId AND us.userRole =:userRole");
        query.setParameter("mobileNo", mobileNo);
        query.setParameter("emailId", emailId);
        query.setParameter("userRole", userRole);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> checkUserNameAvailability(String userName) {
        System.out.println("the username is " + userName);
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT us FROM Users AS us WHERE us.userName =:userName");
        System.out.println("the username2 is " + userName);
        query.setParameter("userName", userName);
        System.out.println("the username3 is " + userName);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> checkEmailNMobileVerificationByUname(String userName, Boolean bolVal) {
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT us FROM Users AS us WHERE us.userName =:userName AND us.mobileVerifyStatus =:bolVal AND us.emailVerifyStatus =:bolVal");
        query.setParameter("userName", userName);
        query.setParameter("bolVal", bolVal);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Above is the Domain Class or entity class against my db table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users extends BaseDomain {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private String emailId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "mobile_no")
    private String mobileNo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "dob")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email_verify_code")
    private String emailVerifyCode;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "mobile_verify_code")
    private String mobileVerifyCode;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email_verify_status")
    private boolean emailVerifyStatus;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "mobile_verify_status")
    private boolean mobileVerifyStatus;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "user_role")
    private String userRole;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "login _utc")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date loginUtc;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "registration_utc")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date registrationUtc;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "is_approved")
    private boolean isApproved;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "is_blocked")
    private boolean isBlocked;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId")
    private Collection<AdvisorDocument> advisorDocumentCollection;

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }

    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmailVerifyCode() {
        return emailVerifyCode;
    }

    public void setEmailVerifyCode(String emailVerifyCode) {
        this.emailVerifyCode = emailVerifyCode;
    }

    public String getMobileVerifyCode() {
        return mobileVerifyCode;
    }

    public void setMobileVerifyCode(String mobileVerifyCode) {
        this.mobileVerifyCode = mobileVerifyCode;
    }

    public boolean getEmailVerifyStatus() {
        return emailVerifyStatus;
    }

    public void setEmailVerifyStatus(boolean emailVerifyStatus) {
        this.emailVerifyStatus = emailVerifyStatus;
    }

    public boolean getMobileVerifyStatus() {
        return mobileVerifyStatus;
    }

    public void setMobileVerifyStatus(boolean mobileVerifyStatus) {
        this.mobileVerifyStatus = mobileVerifyStatus;
    }

    public String getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    public Date getLoginUtc() {
        return loginUtc;
    }

    public void setLoginUtc(Date loginUtc) {
        this.loginUtc = loginUtc;
    }

    public Date getRegistrationUtc() {
        return registrationUtc;
    }

    public void setRegistrationUtc(Date registrationUtc) {
        this.registrationUtc = registrationUtc;
    }

    public boolean getIsApproved() {
        return isApproved;
    }

    public void setIsApproved(boolean isApproved) {
        this.isApproved = isApproved;
    }

    public boolean getIsBlocked() {
        return isBlocked;
    }

    public void setIsBlocked(boolean isBlocked) {
        this.isBlocked = isBlocked;
    }

    public Collection<AdvisorDocument> getAdvisorDocumentCollection() {
        return advisorDocumentCollection;
    }

    public void setAdvisorDocumentCollection(Collection<AdvisorDocument> advisorDocumentCollection) {
        this.advisorDocumentCollection = advisorDocumentCollection;
    }

}
```

And the error its throwing that its a mysql sysntax error exception. But according to me the code should work properly but dont know why isn't it not working .
the error that its throwing is as follows

Comment: and you dont post the "mysql syntax error exception" (and its stack trace) or what SQL it was executing at the time.

Comment: *@OP*: What is column `us` in `SELECT us FROM Users AS us`?

Comment: sir actually i am using alias name  for the table  users